# How to benchmark each iteration of a for loop (using JMH)?

Tags: java, maven, microbenchmark, jmh

I've integrated JMH into my maven project. I can benchmark my `doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates)` method successfully

```
    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class BenchmarkContext {

        MigrationManager manager = new MigrationManager();
        MigrationRegistry registry = new MigrationRegistry();
        Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates;

        @Setup
        public void initClient() {
            applicableUpdates = registry.getApplicableUpdates(0);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    @Warmup(iterations = 1)
    @Measurement(iterations = 5)
    public void benchmarkDoUpdate(BenchmarkContext context) throws Exception {
        context.manager.doUpdate(context.applicableUpdates);
    }
```

Now, `doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates)` method calls another method `applyUpdate(Migratable migratable)` within a for loop for each list element(Migratable) in applicableUpdates.

```
public void doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates) throws Exception {
        for (Migratable migratable : applicableUpdates) {
            try {

                applyUpdate(migratable);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Failed to apply migration {}" + migratable, e);
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to benchmark `applyUpdate(Migratable migratable)`. How can I do that?

I don't understand how do I set up its params as it comes from a list from another method `doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates)`. 

Or is there a way to benchmark each iteration of the for loop in `doUpdate(Collection<Migratable> applicableUpdates)`?

Answer (score 0):

> Or is there a way to benchmark each iteration of the for loop

You can use the `@OperationsPerInvocation(<integer>)` to tell JMH how many loops you are doing in the `@Benchmark` method. The downside is that it's an annotation -> hence the parameter can be changed only during "development time"

> I want to benchmark applyUpdate(Migratable migratable). How can I do that?

Just call `applyUpdate(Migratable migratable)` inside the `@Benchamrk` method instead of `doUpdate`.

---

IMO it does not makes sense to benchmark `applyUpdate()` with a list of migratables, because in theend the result will be the average time of all migratables, but sme might take a lot of time, while other might complete almost instantaneous. Hence such benchmark will be useless.

Comment: Thanks, @Svetlin Zarev

Answer (score 0):

You *probably* want to test how much time in takes to `applyUpdate` *for each separate Migratable*. If there are not that many how about providing a `@Benchmark` for each of them? At least in this case you will have a result that you can "take home"; meaning you can see *not how an entire list* is updated; but each at a time...